# Writing to xlsm is not working in c#

Tags: c#, excel-2010

I was trying to write some data's to a macro enabled excel which is create with Microsoft Excel 2010. 
The problem is my code is not writing any datas, also there is no error. can anyone  tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
 private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string excelFilename;
            excelFilename = "D:\\TestPivot1.xlsm";
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ObjExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Workbook ObjWorkBook;
            Worksheet ObjWorkSheet;

            ObjWorkBook = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open(excelFilename, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            ObjWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)ObjWorkBook.Sheets[2];
            int i;
            for(i=1;i<10;i++){
                ObjWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] = "ID";
                ObjWorkSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "NAME";
                ObjWorkSheet.Cells[i, 3] = "GENDER";
                ObjWorkSheet.Cells[i, 4] = "DEPT";
                ObjWorkSheet.Cells[i, 5] = "SALARY";
                ObjWorkSheet.Cells[i, 6] = "DOH";
                ObjWorkSheet.Cells[i, 7] = "LOCATION";
            }
            ObjWorkBook.SaveAs("D:\\TestPivot2.xlsm", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
       Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
       Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
       Missing.Value, Missing.Value);            
        }
```

Comment: Not that much, except that you need `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled`.

Comment: Are you sure you opened the right file, and that there is really no error?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing whole .xlsm file to the interop object, first crate Filestream object then use that object to open excel and then create workbook object with exactly the same name on that you want to modify.

errors: 1) No fileStream object to open .xlsm file
        2) You are passing filepath where you should pass FileStream
        3) when you are done with your required operation then ObjWorkBook.Write(fs); and then close all the objects

Comment: Well, the code works here so I don't know why you want to use file streams.